# Открыть случайную вложенную папку

Tags: cmd, bat

В каталоге находится неопределённое количество вложенных папок. Все вложенные папки первого уровня, то есть внутри них нет других вложенных папок. Нужно выбрать случайную вложенную папку в каталоге и открыть её, например, в проводнике.

В принципе, лет десять назад я писал похожий код для открытия случайного файла в каталоге, но как переделать его для случайной папки - не знаю:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set i=0
for %%f in ("Каталог\*.*") do (
    set file!i!=%%f
    set /a i+=1
)
set /a n=%random% %% %i%
set file=!file%n%!
start "" "%file%"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почти то же самое можно использовать с небольшой модификацией

> FOR /D %переменная IN (набор) DO команда [параметры]
>
> ```
> Если набор содержит подстановочные знаки, команда выполняется
> для всех подходящих имен каталогов, а не имен файлов.
> ```

*Из справки `for /?` в консоли.*

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set i=0

for /D %%d in ("c:\test\folder\*") do (
    set dirs!i!=%%d
    set /a i+=1
)
set /a n=%random% %% %i%
set d=!dirs%n%!
start %windir%\explorer.exe "%d%"
```

Comment: Спасибо, сработало. Теперь можно будет адаптировать код под свои нужды.